# pytesseract eats CPU too high

Tags: ubuntu, tesseract, cpu-usage, python-tesseract

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the pyteserract script eats too high, and it causes system reboot intermittenly.

The top command output is

```
    top - 21:23:31 up 27 min,  4 users,  load average: 3.27, 1.86, 1.28
Tasks: 290 total,   2 running, 216 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 87.5 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 11.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16295836 total, 10387872 free,  2990788 used,  2917176 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16645116 total, 16645116 free,        0 used. 12155216 avail Mem 

  PID USER  PR  NI VIRT    RES     SHR   S %CPU   %MEM  TIME+   COMMAND    
 5391 myid  20   0 1393532 141324  39308 R 667.8  0.9   2:30.57 python
```

the python script is

```
text_eng = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(dst), lang='eng', config='--oem 1 --psm 1 -c preserve_interword_spaces=1')
```

My environment is

```
tesseract 4.1.0-rc1
 leptonica-1.77.0
  libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libopenjp2 2.1.2
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

What I have done are 
1) removed oem option
2) remove psm option
but no luck so far.

Any clue?

Comment: How do you get to 667.8% CPU usage?  I assume that's a percentage of a single core.  How many cores are you running?  For example, if 32 cores, it's not CPU usage that's the problem, but, if less than 7 cores, problem.

Comment: @JimFell Thanks for your attention, cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l returns 
8 so that I think 8 cores! In irix mode, top says 99% of cpu usage. I think the problem comes from tesseract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by myself.

I've removed leptonica-1.77.0 and compiled again, then the problem has been gone.